Cannot access any websites when using whitelist Access Control feature on my TP-Link router
I am following the very basic instructions to set up Access Control on my TP-Link router. I want my hosts to be able to access only a few specific websites, however with my setup, the only website I am able to access is the router admin 192.168.0.1.
However, my hosts are not able to access any of the target domains that I set.
My TP-Link router is connected to my ISP's router and when I disable access control, I am able to access the internet through my TP-Link.




I suggest something much easier to use like piHole or a DNS service that supports content filtering

On the TP-Link site, directions state, "The process of this step is as same as the process of setting the URL blacklist, except choose “Permit” Policy rather than “Deny” Policy." At least two rules are needed:

A blanket (.) Deny rule to block (blacklist) all sites (except for those whitelisted, as below).
A specific Permit rule for one or more site (whitelist).

Note that some sites redirect the browser immediately, or after login, so both URL's must be whitelisted. For example, this might be used to distribute traffic evenly among servers.
More problematic, a page served from one site might have details served from another site. For example, you may allow https:\\www.google.com, but on that page might be an image served from https://blog.google/, which must also be whitelisted to see it. To get a page to display properly might call for adding many Permit URL's.

aha so for every website I allow, I need to also allow the hundreds of websites it may subsequently communicate with ?

If a page is displaying info from another URL, then it would seem so. Areas of the page would be blank, or it might not work at all, otherwise. Test first on a simple static site, such these: https://blog.hubspot.com/website/static-website-examples.
